# Gradients & Minus Front

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to re-create this in illustrator. These are the steps I take with the palm tress; Object>Expand. CMD 8. CMD ALT 2. Highlight All. Minus Front. This process messes up my gradients...

Second question regarding the horizontal lines. If I minus front them first, then try to minus front the palm trees, It cuts out most of the image, not sure what i'm doing wrong here. Thanks 
[image]

Comment: It would be best to set this up with **flat** fills, then do the expanding/pathfinder operations, *then* apply gradients where needed.

Comment: Do the black areas need to be transparent?

Answer (score 1):

Select the different path elements.
Then select the gradient tool.
Drag the gradient from the top to the bottom of your elements.